# Angular Material @ViewChield MatTable: How to update table?

Tags: angular, undefined, viewchild, angular-material-table

I have a child component that uses MatTable.
I need to update the table after edit or create using renderRows();
The table datasource is an @Input().
I have tried onChanges, but I got **undefined** because of @ViewChild.

Where do I have to put renderRows() to update the table when products[] is updated?
In this case, the table is updated, but with an undefined error message.

Child Component:

```js
  //Table datasource
  @Input()
  products: Product[] = [];


  @ViewChild(MatTable)
  table !: MatTable<Product>;

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.table.renderRows(); //works but I got undefined
  }
```

In the parent component, when the state changes:

```js
   this.productService.saveProduct(product).subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.products.push(data);
          }
    });
```

If I instead reload and create a new array, it works perfect, but I don't want to call my rest api:

```js
 loadProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
      next: data => { this.products = data }
    });
  }
```

```js
this.productService.saveProduct(product).subscribe({
          next: data => {
                this.loadProducts()        
          }
});
```

Comment: Could you share how products gets changed in the parent component? Is it e.g. `products.push()` or `products = newProductsArray`

Comment: `this.products.push(data);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply check that the table is defined before calling the function

```js
@ViewChild(MatTable)
  table?: MatTable<Product>;

  ngOnChanges(){
    if (table) this.table.renderRows(); //works but I got undefined
  }
```

`!` means that the variable is always defined, which in this case is not true. Use `?` in these situations and the compiler will help you avoid these types of bugs.

I see that you are hoping `ngOnChanges` will fire when you change the array `Products`. This is not the case as change detection will only check object identity, not value. You can call `ngOnChanges` directly, reassign the array after pushing, or simply create an update function - up to you.

```js
   this.productService.saveProduct(product).subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.products.push(data);
            this.ngOnChanges();
          }
    });
```

or

```js
   this.productService.saveProduct(product).subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.products.push(data);
            this.products = this.products.slice();
          }
    });
```

or

```js
  renderRows(){
    this.table?.renderRows();
  }

  this.productService.saveProduct(product).subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.products.push(data);
            this.renderRows();
          }
  });
```

Comment: It did not works, because @ViewChild will be not defined in ngOnChanges(): 
Angular doc:
 "View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called."

Answer (score 0):

Potencial solution 1:

Now I dont have **undefined** and the the works perfect, but repeat twice the same line looks wrong for me.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource =  new MatTableDataSource(this.products);;
    this.table.renderRows();
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.products);
  }
```

Potencial solution 2:

Parent component always creates a new array when something changes:

```
this.productService.saveProduct(product).subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.products.push(data);
            this.products = Array.from(this.products);
          }
        });
```